# The repository ... no longer has a Release file?

Tags: apt, package-management, kali-linux

Whenever I use update it shows this error. I am new to Linux
How can I fix it ?

```
apt-get update -y
```

```
Ign:1 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/Debian_9.0 ./ InRelease
Err:2 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/Debian_9.0 ./ Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 195.135.221.134 80]
Hit:3 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease             
Hit:4 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease           
Hit:5 https://mirror.karneval.cz/pub/linux/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/Debian_9.0 ./ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Some system information

```
Operating System: Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-kali4-amd64
Architecture: x86-64
Release: 2020.2
```

This is my source.list file

```
deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb-src https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

[image: software and updated sources]

I tried to remove it and upgrade but it's still not allowing upgrading

```
$ apt-get upgrade -y

eading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  [ ..packages.. ]
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  [ ..packages.. ]
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 122 not upgraded.
```

Comment: try `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The repository `http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/Debian_9.0` [doesn't exist (removed)](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/). You can use testing codename instead of debian 9.

Import the release key:

```
wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/Debian_Testing/Release.key -O- |sudo apt-key add -
```

Change directory to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` then edit the lutris repository (something like `lutris.list`) as follows:

```
deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/Debian_Testing/ ./
```

Disable the `precise` repository. Then run :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```